# Plain TeX and BibTeX on Overleaf

Tags: bibtex, plain-tex, overleaf

I'm compiling a Plain TeX project on Overleaf with the line

```
$latex = 'tex %O %S';
```

in the `latexmkrc` file. This makes most things work swimmingly, except BibTeX.

In a file called `main.tex` I have

```
\input btxmac
The \TeX{}book~\cite{knuth:tex} is good.
\medskip
\leftline{\bf References}
\bibliography{mybib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bye
```

and in a file called `mybib.bib` I have

```
@BOOK{knuth:tex,
     author = "Donald E. Knuth",
     title = "The {\TeX}book",
     publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
     year = "1984",
}
```

(These are examples from [Patashnik](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb24-1/patashnik.pdf).)

The problem is that I cannot get it to produce the correct output. I get
[image]
whereas locally, with the exact same files, running

```
tex main
bibtex main
tex main
tex main
```

produces
[image]

Is there something I can add to my `latexmkrc` file to get the same behaviour on Overleaf? Thanks in advance! The Overleaf project is [here](https://www.overleaf.com/2948514243bynzfjmrrxmm) if you would like to tinker (it contains just the minimal example and it should be editable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to cheat :-)

The source `latexmk.pl` states very loosely that:

```perl
                   # In any event bibtex is only run if the log file
                   #   indicates that the document uses bbl files.
```

and this “indicates” means that either LaTeX printed:

```
No file \jobname.bbl.
```

to the `.log`, or `bibtex` was already run and LaTeX read the `.bbl` file, so the `.log` contains:

```
(./\jobname.bbl)
```

But Plain doesn't print `No file \jobname.bbl` to the `.log`, so you have to cheat and print it yourself. Add this to your document:

```
\immediate\write16{No file \jobname.bbl.}%
```

and you're good to go.

You may notice that this will write that line every time, but that's okay because `latexmk` understands anyway and will do the right thing (it ignores this line if the `.bbl` file was input).

Comment: Wow, there was no way I was going to figure that out on my own. This is brilliant!

Comment: This is no cheating but *standard* way, how to run non-LaTeX documents at Overleaf. Unfortunately.

Comment: By non-LaTeX @wipet did you mean we have similar issues when using ConTeX and others?

Comment: @gildux When we are using OpTeX or plain TeX with \input opmac, then we need not to run bibtex at all. Bibtex is old software not supporting Unicode then the best way is to avoid it. OpTeX and OPmac provide direct access to the .bib files, no external program is needed. Simply write $latex = 'luatex -fmt=optex %O %S' to the latexmkrc file and follow the documentation how to use \cite and  \usebib commands.

Comment: Thanks @wipet Your comments are precious.